# Bypassing Mixed Content Warning of http iframe inside https

Tags: javascript, http, iframe, https

I'm developing a new website for our company, and there is a requirement for an iframe of http, inside the production web which is https.

I've seen some suggested solutions such as 'setup my own HTTP proxy' or use google as the ssl proxy, but It didn't work for me.
I was wondering if you might be able to come up with a solution for this issue.

```
<uib-tab index="1" heading="Gm" disabled="vm.gmFailure">
                <div class="panel-body" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
                    <iframe ng-src="{{vm.gmFrameUrl}}" frameborder="0" style="width: 103%;height: 800px; overflow: auto"></iframe>
                </div>
            </uib-tab>
```

In Controller :

```
vm.gmFrameUrl = gmService.trustedSrcUrl(results.data.iframeUrl);
```

Comment: Please link us to the suggested solutions and explain how exactly they didn't work for you.

Comment: get the owners of the iframed content to implement ssl support. http is just going to be increasingly awkward to work with, and the cost/benefit of https mean that there's no really good reason not to use it.